# Xcode 5 - How to activate Emoji keyboard by default

Tags: ios, keyboard, emoji

I want my app to have an only-emoji keyboard. Is this possible to do? Like instead of the english version coming up, it would be emojis. Is it possible to do this without enabling emojis via system preferences? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

No, the Emoji keyboard has to be activated by the user in the Settings app and there is no way to change this from a 3rd party app.